# What are some different sealing methods?

Tags: seals

I'm trying to join two different parts together but it's hard trying to find the best method.

I cannot weld them because they must be able to be removed easily. I  can't use any nuts or bolts because then it won't be interchangeable and for what I'm trying to fit my part on, there are hundred of different variations.

I need out to have a very strong seal like I bolted or welded it on but without having to really do so. It also must be extremely air tight. I need a lot of creation on this one. I thought about making a suction effect but didn't know if it would be strong enough and hold it like bolts would. I'm trying to fit my own cylinder head to a little engine I have.

Comment: What kind of engine is it? Internal combustion? How big is it? Have you worked out what the peak force that's trying to separate your head from the cylinder is? There's a reason they're bolted, even if they need to be removed frequently.

Comment: Why do bolts stop it from being interchangeable ?